# day for Date() and Calendar.dateComponents don't match up

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get the current date to print in a particular format (YYYYMMD) for AWS security credentials and I noticed that when I do `Date()`, the day is the 4th which is the correct value:

```
    let date = Date()
    print("\(date)")  //2016-10-04 00:56:28 +0000
```

Now, I want to print the date in the format I desire so, but I keep getting the day value as the 3rd:

```
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let date = Date()
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date)
    print("\(components.day)")  //Optional(3)
```

S3 is expecting the date to be the 4th.  How can I fix this?

Comment: What time zone is your development phone set for? It's a fair bet that in your time zone the date is ACTUALLY the 3rd, before midnight, but that when you display it in UTC it displays as the 4th.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of time zone difference. `date` will return the UTC time and date but `calendar` will return the date and time based on your device's time zone. If you need the day number in UTC just set the time zone of the calendar object to UTC after you create it:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
```

Now it will always match the value that is returned by `Date()`

Comment: Although it might be better to create a new Gregorian calendar and set the time zone of that calendar to UTC. Won't changing the time zone of the current calendar potentially mess up calendar operations in the rest of your app?

Comment: @DuncanC It will only change the time zone of this `calendar` object. It won't change the `current` calendar.

Comment: But yes, creating a new Gregorian calendar would make it safe across all locales.

Answer (score 1):

When you print a date using

```
 print("\(date)")
```

You get the date and time in UTC, which is probably not what you want.

If you want to display your date in your local time zone, create a date formatter and use that:

```
let dateFormatter = NSdateFormatter()
let dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
let dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium

let dateString = dateFormatter.StringFromDate(date)
print ("date = \(dateString)")
```

If you do this a lot, you might want to create an extension on NSDate displayString so you can use that to display your dates without having to write additional code.

Comment: so Heroku creates a signed request with a date that is in UTC which I need to match on the app.

Comment: Create a gregorian calendar and set it's time zone to UTC. Sam_M's answer shows how to set the time zone of a calendar, but I'd suggest creating a new calendar rather than modifying the current calendar.